# How to preview the <p:graphicImage> after image upload is performed?

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, primefaces, graphicimage

I am using PrimeFaces and I want to show the preview of uploaded image `<p:graphicImage>` immetately after the upload operation is performed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Primefaces Dynamic Image Streaming](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf)

Like this

```
<p:fileUpload update="myImage" fileUploadListener="#{myBean.handleFileUpload}" ....

<p:graphicImage id="myImage" value="#{myBean.chart}" />


private StreamedContent chart;  

File chartFile = new File("someFile");

chart = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(chartFile), "image/png");
```

I took some code snippet from the showcase... But its enough the get the general Idea...

Comment: You said : "I want to show the preview of uploaded image" , You don't have to save it to DB... just keep in your bean for the preview... I don't think you can preview something that you haven't uploaded yet... Unless its from web... and than you can simple use the url in your `p:graphicImage `

Comment: ya here problem is flow .jvm comes streamedContent method after checks the @PostConstruct method So ,nullpointer exception is occur ...

Comment: @ Daniel  ya your right i didn't save the image in DB .then i can't use url also .bcz i want to preview the image before going to save.

Comment: you dont have to save to db in order to preview.. keep it in your bean and use `new DefaultStreamedContent...` as a source of your `p:graphicImage ` make your bean a view scoped atleast...

Comment: My code is 'StreamedContent fileStream;
  getter&setter...
  public void save()throws IOException{
   ...
   fileStream = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(getFile()),"image/jpeg");
   ...}
  UI  <p:graphicImage id="refreshMe" value="#{Controller.fileStream}"  />   '

Comment: Above code shows exception can't  find the property filestream

Comment: `Controller.fileStream` ? with capital C letter ??? anyway it looks like some basic JSF issue.... is it managed bean with session /view annotation at all ?